# Selecting a column with reference to MAX(addDate) from date column

Tags: mysql, database

i have this `ai_invoice` table.

[image]

i want to select the lastPaymentAmount and lastPaymentDate with reference to date column.

for lastPaymentDate i used MySQL's `MAX()` here is what i did.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(ai_account.amount) as amountPaid, 
  MAX(ai_account.addDate) as lastPaymentDate 
FROM ai_account 
WHERE ai_account.trader_id = :traderId
```

i am confused on how to select lastPaymentAmount based on lastPaymentDate. the result i am expecting  is `3434`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you have to do

```
SELECT 
  ai_account.amount as amountPaid, 
  ai_account.addDate as lastPaymentDate 
FROM ai_account 
WHERE ai_account.id = (
    SELECT 
    id
    FROM ai_account 
    WHERE ai_account.trader_id = :traderId
    ORDER BY ai_account.addDate DESC
    LIMIT 1
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  ai_account.amount as amountPaid, 
  ai_account.addDate as lastPaymentDate 
FROM ai_account 
WHERE ai_account.addDate = (SELECT MAX(ai_account.addDate) FROM ai_account
  WHERE ai_account.trader_id = :traderId) AND ai_account.trader_id = :traderId;
```

The sub query selects the last `ai_account.addDate` from `traderId` and the parent WHERE clause forces the rows to this date and to this id.

This could result in more then one record (two paiments the same day by the same trader). To overcome this you can use

```
SELECT 
  SUM(ai_account.amount) as amountPaid, 
  MAX(ai_account.addDate) as lastPaymentDate 
...
```